# Autowiring any of an Interface using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want autowire a class which implements in a Component. Here is a part of the interface:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class GenericResourceHandlerService<T extends ResourceRequest, A extends ResultType, B extends ResourceService<T, A>> {

    private final B service;

    public Response get(String x) {
        various checks(x, service.getType());

        B res = service.get(x);

        if (res!= null) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(res).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, a class which implements ResourceService would look like this:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class TypeOneService implements EntityService<CityRequest, City> {

    private final Repository repository;

    @Override
    public ResultType getType() {
        return ResultType.TYPE_ONE;
    }

    @Timed
    public TYPE_ONE get(String resource) {
        return repository.get(resource);
    }

}
```

And the interface itself, looks like this:

```
public interface EntityService<T extends EntityRequest, A extends ReturnableEntity> {

    ResourceType getResourceType();

    A get(String resource);

}
```

Now, I have a set of controllers which tries to autowire `GenericResourceHandlerService` and call it's get method. Which looks like this:

```
public class TypeOneController {

    private final TypeOneService typeOneService;

    private final GenericResourceHandlerService<TypeOneRequest, TypeOne, TypeOneService> genericResourceHandlerService;

    public Response getListItemByResource(
        String resource
    ) {
        return genericResourceHandlerService.get(resource);
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
public class TypTwoController {

    private final TypeTwoService typeTwoService;

    private final GenericResourceHandlerService<TypeTwoRequest, TypeTwo, TypeTwoService> genericResourceHandlerService;

    public Response getListItemByResource(
        String resource
    ) {
        return genericResourceHandlerService.get(resource);
    }
}
```

This compiles but when the app starts then, then I get the following error message:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in path.GenericResourceHandlerService required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - typeOneSerivce: defined in file [C:\Path\TypeOneService.class]
    - typeTwoService: defined in file [C:\Path\TypeTwoService.class]
```

I think this is because, Spring Boot can't work out which one to service to autowire with. Is it possible what I am trying to do?

Comment: You have to use @Qualifier annotation for this kind of requirment.

Comment: @Sambit Where? I need to do something on the controller classes as that is where the autowiring is done.

Comment: Check this link.https://memorynotfound.com/handling-multiple-autowire-dependencies-with-spring-qualifier/

Answer (score 0):

Spring tries to inject a bean to resolve the `GenericResourceHandlerService.service` but service has type B and B extends ResourceService. And spring found 2 beans implementing this interface so doesn't know which implementation to autowire..

You can put `@Qualifier` on field `service` but I imagine you will lost the genericity of this type `GenericResourceHandlerService`

Maybe the best way is to let the controller pass through the implementation in the `GenericResourceHandlerService` and let this last as a simple pojo..not a spring bean (so remove `@Service` on `GenericResourceHandlerService`

Like this

```
public class TypeOneController {

@Autowired
private final TypeOneService typeOneService;

private final GenericResourceHandlerService<TypeOneRequest, TypeOne, TypeOneService> genericResourceHandlerService = new GenericResourceHandlerService(typeOneService);

public Response getListItemByResource(
    String resource
) {
    return genericResourceHandlerService.get(resource);
}
```

}